# Synchronize 2 database in django

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql

I have 2 different server running django in it. (using postgre)
Both has the same user table. 
I wanted to synchronize the user table, as if I update or delete user in one server then the  2 db should also get updated.
I guess replication is not a solution for my case.
Can anyone point me in right directions. or any link or reference will be helpful.
Both server are running different django code.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do this in PostgreSQL, but in MySQL you could create database VIEW pointing to a table in another database. This way you could reuse the existing `auth_user` table in the other sever.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [pgpool-II](http://pgpool.projects.postgresql.org/pgpool-II/doc/pgpool-en.html). I haven't used it myself, but it's been recommended to me for similar purposes and after a bit of research I came to the conclusion that it's one of the better projects out there.